# in vite js, how can i remove the html extension from urls

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, vite

I am using vite js and when i use `<a href="click.html">Click</a>` the url opens correctly, (for example) [www.example.com/click.html](http://www.example.com/click.html). When i try to remove the html extension from appearing `<a href="click">Click</a>` it just writes (for example) [www.example.com/click](http://www.example.com/click) and refreshes the index.html page. What could i do to fix it? is there something i should do to vite.config.js?

Comment: @Andy noone uses it in production

Comment: @Andy why did you ask that?

Comment: @Andy dude, he didn't mean that way. I mean, `/click.html` serve html file, but `/click` endpoint serves not just html file (even though the user wants to refer to another html page). He wants something aesthetic, you know... `https://example.com/app` will be better than `https://example.com/app.html`

Comment: @Andy well, the browser knows it from the HTTP headers. e.g `Content-Type: text/html`